# Virtuoso SPARQL not retrieving values

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I am uploading a RDF file to a Virtuoso Repository vía de graphic interface (ODS-Briefcase). The file is uploaded successfully. However, every time I make a SPARQL query, an empty result is returned.

I have tried with many other files, and I did not have this problem.

This file size is bigger than the previous ones (14MB), so I guess this could be the cause, but I am not sure about it.

Any help in this matter will be appreciated :)

**UPDATE**
I have tried uploading a smaller file (2KB) and the SPARQL returns results as expected.
[image: SPARQL query]

[image: Result]

However, I uploaded again the file (14 MB) and it seems it is not correctly uploaded.

When I try to read it from the ODS-Briefcase of Virtuoso, this happens:
[image: Error Reading]

Comment: Hard to say without seeing data and query. Maybe wrong graph used? Do you upload it into a separate graph? What is returned for `SELECT * {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 1`  ?

Comment: Have you tried with the quad store file upload?

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions are often answered faster and more accurately via the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp)...

Comment: @AKSW Yeah, I tried to upload it to different graphs and the same happens

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov All my RDF have been manually stored into the WebDAV, because I do not have access to the Quad Store (Conductor). I cannot remember the password when I installed it :(, so maybe I should delete everything and re-install it (and write the password in a paper at least)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve problems like this you have to fundamentally understand the task you are performing and how its interpreted using Virtuoso.

Task at hand:
Loading an RDF document into Virtuoso's WebDAV repository (for which ODS-Briefcase provides a front-end), in a manner that results in the content of said RDF document being loaded into the Quad Store (where RDF data is indexed and made available to SPARQL Queries etc.).

How you achieve your goal:

Use the ODS-Briefcase UI to create a DET Folder (a folder then provides an automatic conduit between WebDAV storage and the Virtuoso Quad Store) of type: Linked Data Import. One of the attributes (characteristics) of this kind of folder is a Named Graph IRI and Named Graph IRI Base:

[image]

With your Linked Data Import DET folder in place, you simply upload RDF documents to the newly created folder.

To verify existence of RDF Language statements imported from an RDF Document placed in this folder simply execute one of the following

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM {targe-named-graph-iri}
WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM {targe-named-graph-iri}
WHERE {?s ?o ?o}
```

You can also leverage Virtuoso's in-built RDF data import middleware (a/k/a Sponger) within a SPARQL query using the pattern:

```
DEFINE get:soft "replace" 
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM {rdf-document-uri}
WHERE {?s ?o ?o}
```

I hope this brings clarity to options available for importing RDF Document content into the Virtuoso Quad Store (Engine that manages Data represented and RDF Property/Predicate Graphs).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have loaded your files into the Virtuoso WebDAV (file) repository, but you may have not loaded the RDF therein into the Virtuoso (RDF) Quad Store.

See this [guide to the bulk loader](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader), and this [page of RDF loading methods](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert).

(ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: I have read the "RDF loading methods" you mention and just followed the "Example Using Linked Data Import folder and Upload from File" step by step. Previous times, and with smaller files it works. I mean, it uploads the file both to the WebDAV and the QuadStore. However, I do not understand the "Bulk Loader" part. I do not know where or how I can execute this commands (ld_dir for example )

Comment: Large files may take a long time to load, and timeouts may be an issue at several layers. I wonder whether you're running with current Virtuoso and VADs (e.g., ODS-Briefcase)? The bulk loader commands (e.g., `ld_dir`) are executed in iSQL; you can use either the browser-based interface, or the command-line tool. Do be aware that filepaths for bulk loading are always machine-local to the Virtuoso instance, even when you're working through the browser-based interface.

Comment: Yes, I am working with the ODS-Briefcase interface, so I guess I am running with the current Virtuoso and VADs?? I finally split my RDF file into smaller parts and upload it. I know it is not the correct approach, since in the future I will have the same problem. However, I needed a fast solution, and this was one. Could you please help me how/where I can find the iSQL brower-based interface?? For further information, I have Virtuoso runing on a Ubuntu Virtual Machine, and I am accessing it from a Windows OS computer.  I would like to manage everything (file upload, update etc) from Windows.

Comment: To be clearer — the Virtuoso version is best checked with commandline output of `virtuoso -?`; the VAD version is found in the *Conductor* -> *System Admin* -> *Packages* page,  `http://virtuoso-host:port/conductor`. The browser-interface to iSQL is alongside the Conductor, accessible via `http://virtuoso-host:port/` ...  Further back-and-forth is not appropriate to StackOverflow; better to use the resources in my comment on your question.